# Meaning of "issue" in a law

Tags: united-states, trusts-and-estates, legal-terms

Below is a quote from the laws of the United States. It in Chapter 26, section 672(c):

> (c) Related or subordinate party For purposes of this subpart, the
> term “related or subordinate party” means any nonadverse party who is—
> (1) the grantor’s spouse if living with the grantor; (2) any one of
> the following: The grantor’s father, mother, **issue**, brother or sister;
> an employee of the grantor; a corporation or any employee of a
> corporation in which the stock holdings of the grantor and the trust
> are significant from the viewpoint of voting control; a subordinate
> employee of a corporation in which the grantor is an executive. For
> purposes of subsection (f) and sections 674 and 675, a related or
> subordinate party shall be presumed to be subservient to the grantor
> in respect of the exercise or nonexercise of the powers conferred on
> him unless such party is shown not to be subservient by a
> preponderance of the evidence.

I do not understand the word ***issue***. It does not make sense to me, and I suspect that it has some legal meaning that I do not understand.

Comment: I edited to make your title more specific.  Otherwise, "trying to understand something about the law" could be the title of every single question on this site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Issue* in this sense [means](https://dictionary.law.com/Default.aspx?selected=1032)

> a person's children or other lineal descendants such as grandchildren and great-grandchildren. It does not mean all heirs, but only the direct bloodline.

Comment: *Issue* is also generally restricted to the *legitimate* bloodline.

Comment: If you're listening to a deposition and "issue" is followed by "Gesundheit", it may have been a sneeze and not a legal term. :D